# libboost_program_options.so not found even though the package is installed

Tags: package-management, boost

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10. I have packages `libboost-program-options1.58-dev`, `libboost-all-dev` installed, but the library itself is apparently not present:

```
$ sudo find / -name libboost_program_options
```

Only boost libs that are present are:

```
$ l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libboost                                                                                                                                                    
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   67K Oct 14 15:53 libboost_date_time.so.1.58.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   95K Oct 14 15:53 libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   95K Oct 14 15:53 libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   15K Oct 14 15:53 libboost_system.so.1.58.0
```

I get following error with some programs:

```
$ vera++
vera++: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such  file or directory
FAIL
```

What is wrong with the packages?

UPDATE:

```
 $ apt-cache policy libboost1.58-dev                                 
libboost1.58-dev:
  Installed: 1.58.0+dfsg-3.1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.58.0+dfsg-3.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.58.0+dfsg-3.1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

 $ sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-program-options-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.

 $ dpkg -L libboost-program-options1.58-dev                          [14:12:23]
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-program-options1.58-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-program-options1.58-dev/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/share/doc/libboost-program-options1.58-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so

 $ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so         [14:13:01]
cat: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Please add output of `apt-cache policy libboost-program-options1.58-dev` to your question.

Comment: I changed the package name. The file is there, if the package is installed. `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` ?

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev`? What is the output?

Comment: You can see ALL the files (and where they are) installed by a package with `dpkg -L` (read `man dpkg`). `dpkg -L libboost-program-options1.58-dev`, and `dpkg -L  libboost-all-dev`.

Comment: I updated the question with relevant outputs

Answer (score 5):

You need to install libboost-program-options-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev
```

Once this is installed, you can run the find command to locate it:
On 16.04 i fount it at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0