# libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when I tried to install some software I got this error

> error while loading shared libraries:   libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

EDIT:

I already have libboost1.55 on my comupter

> ~$ dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp

gives the output:

> libboost1.55-dev: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/730123/libboost-program-options-so-not-found-even-though-the-package-is-installed

Comment: I tried the suggestions in the post but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I used the `rcdcap` program, but when i type the command:

```
sudo rcdcap
```

then the error appears:

```
rcdcap: error while loading shared libraries:
libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Pay attention to `rcdcap`, this error starts with it, this occurs due to the incompatibility of the version itself.

These shared libraries work in coordination with the new non-standard version. Your program version does not rely on obsolete or downgraded packages, this prevents it to work correctly, try installing the older, most appropriate version.

Delete which you have, **considered on the example of using the program `rcdcap`**:

- `sudo apt list --installed`
- `sudo apt remove *your program* #rcdcap version 0.7.99`

Please install a compatible version:

- `sudo dpkg -i *your program* #RCDCap-0.6.0-complete-nodeps-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb`
- `sudo *your program* #missing error`